# Generating Nagios reports in PHP

Tags: php, cgi, report, nagios

In Nagios CGI there are a lot of information about defined services which is not available in `status.dat` file. e.g. `PERCENT_TOTAL_TIME_UP`. I mean parsing `status.dat` will not display any information about service availability.

How can I generate these reports in PHP so I could retrieve the information about service availability?

Comment: Why did you tag this with Perl?

Comment: Because `PERCENT_TOTAL_TIME_UP` is related to a Perl module called Nagios-Report.